# Maximum overlapping datetime range by month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with bookings :

```
 - id
 - isok (boolean)
 - start (datetime)
 - end (datetime)
```

This table represents cars parked between start and end.
I need to get the maximum number of car parked at the same time during a month, for every month between two dates ($limit_start and $limit_end) (and only for bookings with isok at true).

So in the end I need something like this:

(with $limit_start at 01-10-2015 and $limit_end at 31-12-2015)

[10-2015: 7, 11-2015: 12, 12-2015: 9]

Is there a simple way to do this with php and mysql ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: it doesn't look like MySQL - there is no WITH clause in MySQL and the boolean type is normally converted to tinyint.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this, though it might need some adjustments

```
select date_format(start,'%m-%Y') as my,count(*) from table 
where isok=1 and 
start >= '2015-01-10 00:00:00' and end<='2015-12-31 23:59:59' 
group by my 
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be some mistakes in it, but first you query results like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id,YEAR(MAX(start,:limit_start)) as ts_year, MONTH(MAX(start,:limit_start)) as ts_month, 1 as status FROM bookings WHERE start BETWEEN :limit_start AND :limit_end OR end BETWEEN :limit_start AND :limit_end
UNION ALL
SELECT id, YEAR(MIN(end,:limit_end)) as ts_year, MONTH(MIN(end,:limit_end)) as ts_month, -1 as status FROM bookings WHERE start BETWEEN :limit_start AND :limit_end OR end BETWEEN :limit_start AND :limit_end )
ORDER BY ts_year,ts_month
```

After that, you loop through the result set with php and store the maximum values per month.

```php
<?php
$stat=[];
foreach($result as $item)
{
 $key=$item['ts_year'].'-'.$item['ts_month'];
 if(!isset($stat[$key]))
 {
  $stat[$key]=['current'=>0,'max'=>0];
 }

 $stat[$key]['current']+=$item['status']; //add 1 if arrived or -1 if left

 if($stat[$key]['max']<$stat[$key]['current'])
     $stat[$key]['max']=$stat[$key]['current'];
}
?>
```

In the end, $stat[$key]['max'] values are what you are looking for.